# Clickhouse difference between elements with different indexes in the array

Tags: clickhouse

I have the next challenge.
We have pricing ranges that are set in group Array like
`[[1,1000],[1001, 2000], [2003,5000]]`

Is it any possibility to receive difference between second element of x array and first element of x+1 array.
In the results, I need something like
`[1,3]`

Or I can make a flatten list and do arrayDifference between all the elements but then I receive
`[999,1,999,3,2997]`

How can I get odd elements only using only clickhouse functions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT
    arrs,
    arrayMap(index -> arrs[index][1] - arrs[index - 1][2], range(2, length(arrs) + 1)) AS result
FROM 
(
    /* test data set */
    SELECT [] AS arrs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [[1, 1000]] AS arrs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [[1, 1000], [1001, 2000]] AS arrs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [[1, 1000], [1001, 2000], [2003, 5000]] AS arrs
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT [[1, 1000], [1001, 2000], [2003, 5000], [5008, 7890]] AS arrs
)

/*
┌─arrs───────────────────────────────────────────┬─result──┐
│ []                                             │ []      │
│ [[1,1000]]                                     │ []      │
│ [[1,1000],[1001,2000]]                         │ [1]     │
│ [[1,1000],[1001,2000],[2003,5000]]             │ [1,3]   │
│ [[1,1000],[1001,2000],[2003,5000],[5008,7890]] │ [1,3,8] │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────┘
*/
```